# Problema con posicionamiento de "containers" en CSS [Nuevo, Primer Post]

Tags: css

Soy algo nuevo en CSS y tengo el siguiente problema:

Las "contenedores" de debajo que pone MIAMI USA, MUNICH GERMANY y BARCELONA SPAIN con sus correspondientes imágenes posteriores, no entiendo cómo centrar el contenido en el medio, justo debajo de donde pone HIGHLIGHTS. Miren aqui he subido la página web entera a Github para que puedan ver todo el HTML y CSS que escribí: https://github.com/MiguelGarciaRodriguez98/travel-page
(Soy nuevo y es mi primer post, ¡gracias a quién me ayude!) (Si necesitan algo más díganme pero creo que ahi deberían poder ver todo en ese link de Github)

[image: Imagen de cómo se ve en navegador]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu codigo debe ir aca.

Comment: Saludos, esos contenedores te interesaría tenerlos dentro de un <div> y luego con css le puedes dar las propiedades inline, inline-block, inline-flex o inline table para centrar el contenido.

Puede que te sea de ayuda el siguiente link: https://devcode.la/tutoriales/como-centrar-un-div-con-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías utilizar flexbox.
Te paso todo el section highlights, lo que hice fué encerrar los ul en un div, para que todo sea un mismo bloque y todo eso lo encerré en otro div padre, al que le aplicarémos display flex y justify-content-center

Quedando el HTML así:

```
 <section id="highlights">
            <h2>Highlights</h2>
            <div id="placesContainer">
                <div>
            <ul id="destinations">
                <li class="destination">
                    <img src="/images/places/miami.jpg" alt="Miami streets on sunny day">
                    <p>Miami <strong>USA</strong></p>
                </li>
                <li class="destination">
                    <img src="/images/places/munich.jpg" alt="Munich stadium in winter">
                    <p>Munich <strong>Germany</strong></p>
                </li>
                <li class="destination">
                    <img src="/images/places/barcelona.jpg" alt="Palm beach in Barcelona">
                    <p>Barcelona <strong>Spain</strong></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

Y en styles.css, agregamos las siguientes líneas:

```
#placesContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Esto debería ser suficiente, cualquier cosas estoy a las órdenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sorprende que fuese tan sencillo viendo esto, probé cosas muy complejas y me lié mucho, que bueno que me ayudaste muchas gracias.

Comment: Merece, estoy a las órdenes.